# Dash border not displaying properly in drop down menu, either showing none or twice as much

Tags: html, css

I'm facing problem displaying dashed border properly. It's either not showing or showing twice as much. Anyone know how to solve this issue? Thanks

if I didn't add border code for it, no dash will be shown at all
[image]

but if I place dash code it'll show double layer of dash
[image: dash](http://screencast.com/t/9H4iwxUQXU)![enter image description here]

```
<style>
.border{
border-width:1px;    
border-style: none none dashed none; 
border-color: #ffffff; 
}
#borderer{

height:31px;
padding:3px 0;
box-shadow: 0 1px #62183b;
background-color:#000000;

}
#header{
height:30px;
border-width:1px;    
border-style: dashed none; 
border-color: #ffffff; 

color:#E0D4B1;
text-shadow: -1px -1px #db921e;

background-color:#000000;
}

#buttons{
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    left:-50%;
    font-size:20px;
}
#buttons ul{
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    left:50%;
}
#buttons ul li{

        float: left;
        width: 110px;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 20px;
}

#buttons  ul li ul{
    left:0%;
    position:relative;

}

#buttons ul li a{
        display: block;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        color: #ffffff;
        background-color:#000000;
        text-decoration: none;
}

#buttons ul li a:hover{
        color:#000000;
        background:#ffffff;

}
#buttons ul li ul{
        display: none;

}

#buttons ul li:hover ul{
     display: block; /* display the dropdown */

}

</style>

<div id="borderer">
<div id="header">
<div id="buttons">
 <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Products &#9662;</a>
            <ul>
                <li class="border"><a href="#">Laptops</a></li>
                <li class="border"><a href="#">Monitors</a></li>
                <li class="border"><a href="#">Printers</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Answer is given cleary but still it is marked as not useful.

Answer (score -1):

check this in snippet now, what i was trying to explain.

```css
.border {
    border-bottom: 1px dashed red;
  margin-top:1px;
}
#borderer {
    background-color: #000000;
    box-shadow: 0 1px #62183b;
    height: 31px;
    padding: 3px 0;
}
#header {
    border: 1px dashed #fff;
    color: #e0d4b1;
    height: 30px;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px #db921e;
}
#buttons {
    float: right;
    font-size: 20px;
    left: -50%;
    position: relative;
}
#buttons ul {
    left: 50%;
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
#buttons ul li{

        float: left;
        width: 114px;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 20px;
}

#buttons  ul li ul{
    left:0%;
    position:relative;

}

#buttons ul li a{
        display: block;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        color: #ffffff;
        background-color:#000000;
        text-decoration: none;
}

#buttons ul li a:hover{
        color:#000000;
        background:#ffffff;

}
#buttons ul li ul{
        display: none;

}

#buttons ul li:hover ul{
     display: block; /* display the dropdown */

}
```

```html
<div id="borderer">
<div id="header">
<div id="buttons">
 <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Products &#9662;</a>
            <ul>
                <li class="border"><a href="#">Laptops</a></li>
                <li class="border"><a href="#">Monitors</a></li>
                <li class="border"><a href="#">Printers</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Use this

```
.border{
border-bottom:1px dashed #fff;
}
```

insted of

```
.border{
border-width:1px;    
border-style: none none dashed none; 
border-color: #ffffff; 
}
```

Comment: I use border-top it's still the same, guess it's more like a short form of writing rather than a solution to solve this though. Thanks for the suggestion anyways. :)

Comment: no this will display only bottom border and this is what you want. and the code you are using that will display border for all sides.

Comment: As you can see...I am using the border top and border bottom to quickly demonstrate my problem in the two screen shot. currently my problem is that when I didn't put a border for the line at the first box, the original dashed will not be shown, but when I put dash for it. it will display dash twice as much.

Comment: ok so.border {
    border-bottom: 1px dashed red;
  margin-top:1px;
} use this

Comment: nope doesn't work... http://screencast.com/t/30zI9q6jaBA now it's showing one line gap between the buttons and now there's 2 layers of border with a bit of offset